# How to wait for Meteor subscription before launching angular app

Tags: angularjs, meteor

- I am using **angular-meteor** with **pascalprecht.translate**
- the **translations object have to be stored in the database** in order that some users can modify the translations via a back-office
- I subscribe the collection containing the translations and loads them in the .config()
- it works well BUT when loading the application the page is rendered before the subscription is ready.an during a short period of time the texts are not translated.
- I have to do something in order that we always see translations even during the begining

My question is the following:
**Is it possible to make angular wait for the subscription to be ready before it is launched ?**

Best regards

bboisvert

```
angular.module('test').config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {

    Meteor.subscribe('settings', function(){
        test = Settings.findOne({name: "translations"});
        $translateProvider.translations('fr-FR', test['fr-FR']);
        $translateProvider.translations('en-EN', test['en-EN']);
    });

}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Meteor.subscribe` callback, you could do `$rootScope.$broadcast('meteorSubscribed')`

on your root-level directive/controller listen for it and set a `$scope` variable to say it is loaded.  You could then use that variable for `ng-if` or `ng-show`

example:

```
$scope.$on('meteorSubscribed', function(){
    $scope.meteorReady = true;
});
```

in template:

```
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="RootController" ng-show="meteorReady">
    <!-- your app here -->
</div>
```

You could also circumvent the whole event + controller setup and just set `$rootScope.meteorReady = true;` right in the `Meteor.subscribe` callback.  Really depends on the setup of your app.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response you saved my day!
I had to use a hack to make it work because $rootScope cannot be injected into config() block or $translateProvider cannot be injected into run() block.
To solve this, I defined a global variable: `var translateProvider = null;` before module definition then I linked it to the translateProvider in the config block `translateProvider = $translateProvider;` and then I moved my 'subscribe' call to the run() block where I used my variable translateProvider instead of $translateProvider.

I does not seems clean but it's the only solution I found.